# Swift 2.1 - Inputing information into a TextView which populates a Textfield at the same time?

Tags: ios, swift, textview, uitextview

I am currently using a framework called "Swift Validator", it only allows for textfields to be used. In my case I need a textView, my question is how do I input information that I type into the textview which then populates a textfield in the background at the same time? as well as when removing inputed text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `UITextViewDelegate` method `textViewDidChange` to listen for changes to the Text View. When the method is called, update the Text Field. Here's an example:

```
func textViewDidChange(theTextView: UITextView) {
    self.textField.text = theTextView.text   
}
```

Don't forget to extend `UITextViewDelegate` and to set the Text View's delegate to `self`.

Comment: I implemented the function but its still not working, I put the function in the Viewdidload correct? I am new to swift.

Comment: You will need to set your View Controller to extend UITextViewDelegate

Comment: I put the function in ViewDidLoad and i put in UITextViewDelegate already. When I type in TextView the text in still not populating UITextField.

Comment: It shouldn't be inside viewDidLoad. It should be in the same class as it.

Comment: What do you mean by the same class? It's in my ViewController.swift. The text field and text view are connected to IBOutlets not an action. Where do I put the code?

Comment: Don't put textViewDidChange inside another function. It's its own function.

Comment: You might just be missing setting the Text View's delegate. Set your text view's delegate to `self`.

Comment: I'll get back to you tomorrow on the progress. Cheers.

Comment: I have marked this question as marked. Thanks for your help.